# How to create empty float?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is survey answer, so the customer can give a score from 0 to 10 and a lot of them leaves the survey empty, but when I do `df.fillna('')`, I can not make math calculations and taking this error `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`, so Im trying to convert this to float with `df['Survey 1'].astype(float)`but again `could not convert string to float: ''` or `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` so somehow after converting NaN 's to empty I have to change the type to float or int in order to make a calculation like this

```
survey_answers = [
(df['Survey 1']<7) & (df['Survey 1']!=''), 
(df['Survey 1']>8) & (df['Survey 1']<11),
(df['Survey 1']>6) & (df['Survey 1']<9)
    ]
results = ['Detractor','Promoter','Passive']
df['NPS Score'] = np.select(survey_answers, results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.astype(int)`:

```
survey_answers = [
(df['Survey 1'].astype(int)<7) & (df['Survey 1']!=''), 
(df['Survey 1'].astype(int)>8) & (df['Survey 1'].astype(int)<11),
(df['Survey 1'].astype(int)>6) & (df['Survey 1'].astype(int)<9)
    ]
```

Comment: still invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''